# "Indicate" or "Provide an indication of"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between "indicate" and "provide an indication of"? If not, is there any reason that an author prefers one to the other?

For example:

> The next section of the chapter attempts to present an overview of trends at global, regional, country and destination levels. It provides an indication of the scale and scope of the tourism system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particular difference in literal meaning, but *indicate* is actively voiced and *provide an indication of* is passive.

Academic texts, like textbooks and formal papers, have tended to favor (passive voice!) the passive voice as a matter of style. From what I understand, there is increasing leniency on this from journal editors. Other formats may have other preferences, but as far as I am aware it is a stylistic preference only.

Comment: What do you mean by *there is increasing leniency on this from journal editors*?

Comment: When I read newly published papers in academic journals there seem to be more of them written using the active voice, like "I did [x]", whereas it used to be the case that they were essentially all "[x] was done". When I was an undergraduate and writing academic papers for courses, the preference was so strong that papers using active voice at all would be significantly penalized. The given rationale was that such papers would not be published. I've also heard that this stylistic preference varies a lot by field, so my observation may only apply to biological and medical journals.